Disappearing comment
I posted two comments on this (quickly closed) post.  My first comment disappeared.  In it I explained my closure vote (which I think is polite to do). I also explained how I thought the post could be improved.  I was trying to give a friendly guide to "writing a better question”.
Was I not friendly enough? I am genuinely confused!

I find that if someone flags a comment there are pretty good odds a moderator will delete it.

If OP's account is accurate, then it doesn't sound like the kind of comment anyone would flag, or the kind a moderator would delete if someone did flag it. Probably only a moderator can tell what actually happened. Moderators do keep an eye on this meta site.

I have raised this in the mods' private chat room.

I would not be surprised if downvote is one of the Seven Dirty Words? See also: How is it possible that a single user who is not a moderator can delete a comment?

@DavidRoberts: Once the issue is clarified, please post a brief answer in order to close the question.

The post is not available(at least to me). Is it  deleted?

Yes, it was deleted 13 days ago by Stefan Kohl (who says as much in his answer, below).

The comment got flagged as "unfriendly or unkind" by a 10k+-user. To me, suggesting to someone that they apologize or thank for something feels a bit rude, even if it is wrapped in kind words, so I marked the flag as "helpful" and deleted the comment. Other people may feel different about this, so I have restored your comment now.
(Technically, this required temporary undeletion the meanwhile deleted question.)

But the comment did not suggest apologizing or thanking; it suggested rewriting a post that already included an apology and a thank you, to add additional details (incl. a proper question).

Thank you very much for explaining what happened.  I think I understand the order of events now, and it sort of (???) makes sense.  I was not asking the original poster to "make an apology".  Instead I was suggesting that they leave in the "apology" that they already had written (see their first paragraph).  I should have said "your first paragraph is perfect, leave that."  Live and learn, I suppose!

Oops - Emil beat me to it by 40 seconds.

A tangential question: I’m surprised by the “10k+ user”. Until now, I have thought that flags are presented anonymously; does this mean that moderators can actually see who raised a particular flag?

@EmilJeřábek See here: What exactly can moderators see when one raises a flag?

Oh, I see. Thank you.
